# oracle sql query time periods union of set

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a oracle database that has the following tables.How can i count the usage time of each room?
Time periods may overlap for each room,
The table structure is as follows。

**t_room_electricity**

```
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  roomcode  |     starttime      |        endtime     |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|        123 | 2019/5/10 10:00:00 | 2019/5/10 11:30:00 |
|        123 | 2019/5/10 10:30:00 | 2019/5/10 11:00:00 |
|        456 | 2019/5/10 11:00:00 | 2019/5/10 12:00:00 |
|        456 | 2019/5/10 13:00:00 | 2019/5/10 14:00:00 |
|        456 | 2019/5/10 13:30:00 | 2019/5/10 15:00:00 |
|        789 | 2019/6/10 14:22:00 | 2019/6/10 14:26:00 |
|        789 | 2019/6/10 14:31:00 | 2019/6/10 14:36:00 |
|        886 | 2019/6/10 14:32:00 | 2019/6/10 14:35:00 |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: count the time periods union of set for each room

Comment: Can you share the expected output too

Comment: 123  60minute,  456   180minute,  789  9minute,  886  3mintue

Comment: I suppose you meant 210 as expected output for "456" since it has 60+60+90 minutes

Comment: you can add 456    2019/5/10 14:30:00 2019/5/10 16:00:00  ,  replace 456 |2019/5/10 13:45:00 |2019/5/10 15:05:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating Answer to cater to the cases mentioned by OP.

**USING MATCH_RECOGNIZE**

```
  with data
    as (
    select *
      from t_room_electricity
      match_recognize(
      partition by roomcode
      order by starttime
      measures
        first(starttime) f_starttime
        ,last(starttime) l_starttime
        ,first(endtime)  f_endtime
        ,last(endtime)   l_endtime
        ,min(starttime) as min_starttime
        ,max(endtime) as max_endtime
        ,match_number() as mn
        ,classifier() as cls
      pattern(strt group1*)
      define group1
          as starttime<first(endtime)
      )
    )
select roomcode
      ,round(sum((max_endtime-min_starttime)*24*60)) as diff_in_minutes
 from data
 group by roomcode
```

See Output
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=783140ede5dfbf8088a6ce77232ecef7

**USING SQL**

```
select x.roomcode
      ,count(distinct x.minutes_worked)
 from (
select a.roomcode
       ,a.starttime
       ,a.endtime
       ,a.starttime + lvl/24/60 as minutes_worked
  from t_room_electricity a
  join (select level as lvl
          from dual
          connect by level<=24*60 
        )b
    on b.lvl<=to_number((a.endtime-a.starttime)*24*60)
)x
group by x.roomcode
```

See output..
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2add9344f1335376b2fe32df21f769d6

Updated Answer to cater to overlaps, (based on a new recordset)

```
456 | 2019/5/10 11:00:00 | 2019/5/10 12:00:00 |
456 | 2019/5/10 13:00:00 | 2019/5/10 14:00:00 |
456 | 2019/5/10 13:30:00 | 2019/5/10 15:00:00 |
456 | 2019/5/10 13:45:00 | 2019/5/10 15:05:00 |
```

Considering overlaps the following query can achieve the intended result

```
select roomcode
      ,sum(round(time_in_minutes))
from (
select roomcode
       ,eventdate
       ,case when start_flag=1 
              and (lag(start_flag) over(partition by roomcode order by eventdate asc) = 0 
               or  lag(start_flag) over(partition by roomcode order by eventdate asc) is null)
             then null
            else (eventdate
                 -
                 lag(eventdate) over(partition by roomcode order by eventdate asc)
                 )*24*60
        end as time_in_minutes
from (        
     select roomcode,starttime as eventdate,1 as start_flag from t_room_electricity
      union all
     select roomcode,endtime as eventdate,0 as start_flag from t_room_electricity
     )x
   )y
group by roomcode   


+----------+-----------------------------+
| ROOMCODE | SUM(ROUND(TIME_IN_MINUTES)) |
+----------+-----------------------------+
|      123 |                          90 |
|      456 |                         185 |
|      789 |                           9 |
|      886 |                           3 |
+----------+-----------------------------+
```

This first creates an inner block which stores each eventdatetime into a single column called EventDate. 
Then the step is to check if the previous event was a closed boundary(ie start_flag=1) if it is then it begins counting, other wise it continues computing the difference between the previous event in minutes

After this the results are grouped by roomcode and the time_in_minutes is summed up

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=650b4f0ad7304d7f44e7fabbca160a90

**Old Answer**
You can achieve this by using a group by expression as follows

```
select roomcode,sum((endtime-starttime)*24*60) as diff_in_minutes
 from t_room_electricity
 group by roomcode

+----------+-----------------+
| ROOMCODE | DIFF_IN_MINUTES |
+----------+-----------------+
|      123 |             120 |
|      789 |               9 |
|      456 |             210 |
|      886 |               3 |
+----------+-----------------+
```

See dbfiddle link.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=16fd05220157fd274cf0fab4e61c8802

Comment: like 456 2019/5/10 11:00:00 ~ 2019/5/10 12:00:00                                       
             2019/5/10 13:00:00 ~ 2019/5/10 14:00:00                                                 
             2019/5/10 13:30:00 |~2019/5/10 15:00:00                                                     
first:      2019/5/10 11:00:00 ~ 2019/5/10 12:00:00                                    
             2019/5/10 13:00:00 ~ 2019/5/10 15:00:00                                               :  final:     (12-11)*60 + (15-13)*60=180

Comment: 456  has  overlapping time periods,need to combile

Comment: get union of set  first,final using  group by expression

Comment: sorry,I don't know how to get the union or set，  Do you know how to solve it？

Comment: you can add 456 2019/5/10 14:30:00 2019/5/10 16:00:00 , replace 456 |2019/5/10 13:45:00 |2019/5/10 15:05:00

Comment: i add 456 2019/5/10 14:30:00 2019/5/10 16:00:00, expected 240, result 210....

Comment: See example which can fix that issue using match_recognize clause https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=66d3d77b5e4811f181c668d6f4f70bc3. This works if your are > Oracle 12c

Comment: I just verified the data of various situations，This is right，you are a genius，Thank you!!

Comment: USING SQL(connect by levl) executed 490 seconds,can you optimize this sql?             the table (t_room_electricity) has 220000 records.

Comment: descripction--cost , select statement goal=all_rows--910,hash join right outer--910,view--901,sort order by--901,
hash group by--901,view--899,hash group by--899,hash join--898,nested loops--894,table access full--892

Comment: which version of oracle are you on

Comment: you can replace the block b as follows (select rownum as lvl from t_room_electricity where rownum<=24*60)

Answer (score 1):

Work with two tables like room:

```
    with rooms  AS 
(SELECT 123 as room,  to_date('2019/05/10 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')   starttime,    to_date('2019/05/10 11:30:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') endtime from dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 123 as room,  to_date('2019/05/10 10:30:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')   starttime,    to_date('2019/05/10 11:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') endtime from dual 
UNION ALL
SELECT 456 as room,  to_date('2019/05/10 11:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')   starttime,    to_date('2019/05/10 12:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') endtime from dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 456 as room,  to_date('2019/05/10 13:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')   starttime,    to_date('2019/05/10 14:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') endtime from dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 456 as room,  to_date('2019/05/10 13:30:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')   starttime,    to_date('2019/05/10 15:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') endtime from dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 789 as room,  to_date('2019/06/10 14:22:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')   starttime,    to_date('2019/06/10 14:26:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') endtime from dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 789 as room,  to_date('2019/06/10 14:31:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')   starttime,    to_date('2019/06/10 14:36:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') endtime from dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 886 as room,  to_date('2019/06/10 14:32:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')   starttime,    to_date('2019/06/10 14:35:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') endtime from dual)
select room, sum(round((endtime - starttime)*24*60)) from 
(SELECT r1.room,  min(r1.starttime) starttime, nvl(r2.endtime, r1.endtime) endtime  
    FROM rooms r1 left join 
                rooms r2 
    ON (r1.room = r2.room 
    AND r2.starttime between r1.starttime and r1.endtime
    AND r2.starttime <>  r1.starttime)
GROUP BY r1.room, nvl(r2.endtime, r1.endtime))
GROUP BY room
```

output:

```
789 9
123 60
456 180
886 3
```

Comment: the table (t_room_electricity)   has  220000 records,this sql   executed for 32 seconds,i have  add  index for(roomcode,starttime,endtime)

Comment: This works if there is no more than two overlaps within an hour. See an example. roomcode 456 shows 365 minutes when it has worked from 1+1+1 hours +35 minutes or 215 minutes https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bb864617278da85c54aa9db2ecfccfdf

Comment: you are right,if  more  than two overlaps  an hour  ,this  didn't  works.

Comment: you can add 456 2019/5/10 14:30:00 2019/5/10 16:00:00 , replace 456 |2019/5/10 13:45:00 |2019/5/10 15:05:00

Comment: i add 456  2019/5/10 14:30:00  2019/5/10 16:00:00,  expected  240,  result 210....

Comment: You are right there is something missing in my  query. let me try once more

Comment: i have fixed the problems earlier. Does the update query solve your problem